# winload.exe.mui file location in Windows 7 CD

Tags: windows-7

Where can I find the file winload.exe.mui on Windows 7 Enterprise installation CD and how can I extract it from there?

The file location on the installed system is

```
C:\Windows\System32\en-US
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To have the full answer on record:**

The file is indeed in the boot.wim image which should be opened with [Win7 AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=60A07E71-0ACB-453A-8035-D30EAD27EF72&displaylang=en).
AIK contains a command-line tool called imagex that can mount that image into a folder.
The file is in the 2nd path of the image, so the mounting command would look like:
*imagex /mount d:\sources\boot.wim 2 c:\mounted*

In the mounted folder the file is in the same place as after installation, that is c:\mounted\windows\system32\en-US

Comment: good work... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your precious file is on :

[your CD or Win7 installation directory]\sources\boot.wim\2\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-b..os-loader.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7100.0_en-us_e78bb2673919a7bc\

if you can't get this exact directory check for the one who contain **b..os-loader.resources**

Comment: I've edited out the part about corrupted file, thinking it's will keep future answer if they come focused about the real question. Thanks for your edited and improved answer I will check it out.

Comment: Well, it gave me the right direction. it is indeed in boot.wim, thanks.